# Add new element to X different DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I created one element with javascript and would like to add the newly created element to an array of DOM elements. I have the following code but the new element is only added to the last element of the array.

Can you add a created element only once or is there something wrong in the code?

```js
var newElement = document.createElement('a');
newElement.setAttribute("href", "#somewhere");
newElement.innerHTML = 'click me';
$('.tag').each(function() { this.appendChild(newElement); });
```

```css
.tag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  margin: 20px;
}

a {
  background: #fff;
  color #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tag"></div>
<div class="tag"></div>
```

Comment: "If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position" - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Try cloning the element or create new instances inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `cloneNode()` on the node before appending, else the *singular* element will be removed from its previous position in the DOM:

```js
var newElement = document.createElement('a');
newElement.setAttribute("href", "#somewhere");
newElement.innerHTML = 'click me';
$('.tag').each(function() { this.appendChild(newElement.cloneNode()); });
```

```css
.tag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  margin: 20px;
}

a {
  background: #fff;
  color #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tag"></div>
<div class="tag"></div>
```

(you could also create the element in the loop, if you wanted)